# If I train a neural network with CUDA do I need to run the outputted algorithm with CUDA?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, theano-cuda

Let's say I used CUDA to train an object tracking program. Could I then put that program on another computer that didn't have a powerful gpu and run the object tracking program? Or is gpu support required to run the outputted algorithm as well as train it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not matter how you trained your model. You can execute it in completely different scenario, using CPU, GPU, cloud or whatever you want. Since execution is usually much cheaper than training - you will usually need much less powerful hardware.